# MySQL - Kill all sleeping connections

Tags: mysql, database, stored-procedures

How do I remove all idle connections in MySQL without access to the command line? I need a *temporary* solution as one of our services isn't closing its connections properly and flooding the database with idle connections.

Comment: If that misbehaving service is using a distinct MySQL user, you could limit `MAX_USER_CONNECTIONS` for that user: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/user-resources.html If it's okay to kill off that service's connections, then it should be okay to block it from connecting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can kill multiple connections using a stored procedure such as

```
CREATE PROCEDURE kill_all_sleep_connections()
BEGIN
  WHILE (SELECT count(*) as _count from information_schema.processlist where Command = 'Sleep') > 10 DO
    set @c := (SELECT concat('KILL ', id, ';') as c from information_schema.processlist where Command = 'Sleep' limit 1);
    prepare stmt from @c;
    execute stmt;
  END WHILE;
END;
```

This will create a string like `KILL 4312;` for each row matching the `WHERE Command = 'Sleep'` condition, referencing the `id`. Then it `EXECUTE`'s the string as a query, ending the connection.

Use it like this

```
call kill_all_sleep_connections()
```

You should now have less than 10 idle connections on the database instance. The `WHILE` is set to `< 10` as a service might create connections very quickly so increase/decrease as you see fit.

---

You can view *all* the connections with

- `SHOW PROCESSLIST;` or `SELECT * FROM information_schema.PROCESSLIST;`

You can kill a single connection by referencing the `id` in those results using `KILL`

- `KILL 4212;`

---

A proper solution is to close each connection in each service once it is done querying the database.